# Elements hovering in Canvas

Tags: canvas, hover, move, drag

I have quite a simple task. But I've stuck.
The point is to make two elements to change colors to the same, for example, "lime", when one element is on top of the other, and get back to it's own when hovering is done.

Here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/dajest-the-vuer/pen/PdpwQx/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;padding: 20px;
            height: 100vh;
            box-sizing: border-box;

        }

        canvas {
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script defer src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
var cnv = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");
var width = document.body.clientWidth - 40;
var height = document.body.clientHeight - 40;
cnv.width = width
cnv.height = height;
cnv.style.backgroundColor = '#ffa500';

// Draw Figure Method
var drawFigure = function(objectList, color) { 

    for ( var i = 0; i<objectList.length; i++) {

        if ( objectList[i].type === "rect") {
            ctx.fillRect(objectList[i].x,objectList[i].y,objectList[i].w,objectList[i].h);
            ctx.strokeRect(objectList[i].x,objectList[i].y,objectList[i].w,objectList[i].h);
            ctx.fillStyle = objects[i].fillColor;

        }
    }
}


// Objects
var objects = [
    {
        type: "rect",
        name: "One",
        w: 100,
        h: 100,
        x: 50,
        y: 50,
        fillColor: "#FF0000"
    },
    {
        type: "rect",
        w: 100,
        name: "Two",
        h: 100,
        x: 50,
        y: 160,
        fillColor: "#0000ff"
    },
    {
        type: "rect",
        name: "Two-Two",
        w: 100,
        h: 100,
        x: 50,
        y: 270,
        fillColor: "#8a2be2"
    },
]


window.onload = function () {
    drawFigure(objects);
}


cnv.addEventListener("mousedown", onDown, false);

var selectedItem;
function onDown(e) {
    cx = e.pageX;
    cy = e.pageY;

    for ( var i = 0; i<objects.length; i++) {
        if ( cx > objects[i].x && cy > objects[i].y && cx < (objects[i].x + objects[i].w) && cy < (objects[i].y + objects[i].h) ) {
            selectedItem = objects[i];
        }
    }
    console.log (selectedItem)
    cnv.addEventListener("mousemove", onMove, false);
}

function onMove(e) {
    cx = e.pageX;
    cy = e.pageY;
    selectedItem.x = cx - (selectedItem.w / 2) -15;
    selectedItem.y = cy - (selectedItem.h / 2) -15;

    if ( selectedItem.x == 0 || selectedItem.x < 0 ) {
        console.log("EDGE");
        selectedItem.x = 0;
        return
    }

    else if ( (selectedItem.x + selectedItem.w) == (cnv.height) || (selectedItem.x + selectedItem.w) > (cnv.width) ) {
        console.log("EDGE");
        selectedItem.y = cnv.w;
        return
    }

    else if ( selectedItem.y == 0 || selectedItem.y < 0 ) {
        console.log("EDGE");
        selectedItem.y = 0;
        return
    }

    else if ( (selectedItem.y + selectedItem.h) == (cnv.height) || (selectedItem.y + selectedItem.h) > (cnv.height) ) {
        console.log("EDGE");
        selectedItem.y = cnv.height;
        return
    }


    for ( var i = 0; i<objects.length; i++) {
        if( selectedItem == objects[i]) {
            continue
        }
         if ((selectedItem.x + selectedItem.w) > objects[i].x && selectedItem.x > objects[i].x && selectedItem.x < (objects[i].x + objects[i].w)) {
            console.log( "Hovering");

           // Here is the spot. While it is hovering both need to be changed to same color, and back to it's own when hovering is gone.
        }

    }

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.height);
    drawFigure(objects);
}

cnv.addEventListener("mouseup", onUp, false);

function onUp(e) {
    cnv.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMove);
}
```

Comment: Please include relevant code inside the question itself. You can't have only a link to an off-site resource. See posting an [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the snippet below...
 
that is your code but I removed all the stuff that is not needed for your problem.

I'm pushing you in the right direction, now the squares change color when they hover but the condition is only looking at the `X` you need to add the `Y` and test for potential bugs

```html
<style> * { margin: 0px; } </style>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<script>
var cnv = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");
cnv.width = cnv.height = 500;

var objects = [
    { w: 60, h: 60, x: 10,   y: 20, fillColor: "black" },
    { w: 60, h: 60, x: 120,  y: 20, fillColor: "blue" },
    { w: 60, h: 60, x: 240,  y: 20, fillColor: "red" },
]

var selectedItem;
function onMove(e) {
  if (selectedItem) {
    cx = e.pageX;  cy = e.pageY;
    selectedItem.x = cx - (selectedItem.w / 2) -15;
    selectedItem.y = cy - (selectedItem.h / 2) -15;
    var hovering = false
    objects.forEach(function(o) {
      if (o != selectedItem) {
        if ((selectedItem.x + selectedItem.w) >o.x && selectedItem.x >o.x && selectedItem.x < (o.x +o.w)) {
          hovering = true
        }
      }
    })
    if (hovering) {
      if (selectedItem.fillColor != "lime") {
        selectedItem.color = selectedItem.fillColor
        selectedItem.fillColor = "lime"
      }      
    } else if (selectedItem.color) {
      selectedItem.fillColor = selectedItem.color
    }
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.height);
    drawFigure();
  }
}

function onDown(e) {
    cx = e.pageX; cy = e.pageY;    
    objects.forEach(function(o) {
        if ( cx >o.x && cy >o.y && cx < (o.x +o.w) && cy < (o.y +o.h) ) {
            selectedItem =o;
        }
    });
}

function drawFigure() { 
  objects.forEach(function(o) {
    ctx.fillStyle = o.fillColor;
    ctx.fillRect(o.x,o.y,o.w,o.h);
    ctx.strokeRect(o.x,o.y,o.w,o.h);
  });
}

window.onload = drawFigure
cnv.addEventListener("mousemove", onMove, false);
cnv.addEventListener("mousedown", onDown, false);
cnv.addEventListener("mouseup", function () { selectedItem = null });

</script>
```